# Relative position causing problem my container go under the showcase Why It's happening?

Tags: html, css, css-position

## I am caught in problem due to relative position

- My Other content get pushed under the showcase.
- I am giving you full code please tell me what I am doing wrong.
- I have given the link to google drive which cotain screenshot.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.d-4 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

nav ul a {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/24/23/03/railway-2439189_1280.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Website | Getting Started</title>
  <!-- My CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="relative">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><img height="70" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"> &nbsp;Title</a>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <a href="#">SignUp</a>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="showcase">
      <h1 class="d-4">Welcome to my Website.</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Way of heaven is here.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
    <form id="footer" class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
      <input class="input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail">
      <input class="input" type="number" id="mob" placeholder="Enter your phone No.">
      <input class="input" type="textr" id="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

#### Screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hn4-dyx0h8BrY42zAjL4801yCZ_0YYnB/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Where do you want this `div.container` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent overlapping of `showcase` on `container`, add `position: relative;` to `.container`.

And if you want `conatiner` not to overlap with `.relative`, then just just add `height: 100vh;` in `.relative`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.d-4 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

nav ul a {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/24/23/03/railway-2439189_1280.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="relative">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><img height="70" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"> &nbsp;Title</a>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <a href="#">SignUp</a>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="showcase">
      <h1 class="d-4">Welcome to my Website.</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Way of heaven is here.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
    <form id="footer" class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
      <input class="input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail">
      <input class="input" type="number" id="mob" placeholder="Enter your phone No.">
      <input class="input" type="textr" id="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It's worked. After seeing your answer , I realized that due to height of showcase and all element inside relative are going in overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

was such a result needed?

```css
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    a {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 1200px;
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .d-4 {
      font-size: 2.6rem;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .lead {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    .relative {
      display: flex; /* added */
      height: 100vh; /* added */
      flex-direction: column; /* added */
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      display: flex;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: bold;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 0;

    }

    nav > a {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 28px;
      padding: 0 20px;

    }

    nav ul a {
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    nav ul a:hover {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }

    .showcase {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/24/23/03/railway-2439189_1280.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover,rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      background-blend-mode: darken;
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Website | Getting Started</title>
  <!-- My CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="relative">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><img height="70" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"> &nbsp;Title</a>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <a href="#">SignUp</a>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="showcase">
      <h1 class="d-4">Welcome to my Website.</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Way of heaven is here.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
    <form id="footer" class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
      <input class="input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail">
      <input class="input" type="number" id="mob" placeholder="Enter your phone No.">
      <input class="input" type="textr" id="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Noted in css with comments. You can check. Class `relative`.

Comment: @Anurag Kumar, did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank ! 100vh setting up hieght helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:absolute` to your .container. The position property in CSS works like this:

the property-value couple `position:relative` tells your layout which element shall be used as a reference for its child elements which contain the property-value pair `position:absolute`, for their positioning.

Then, you can use the properties `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` to specify the distancing of the child HTML element having the `position: absolute` pair from the edges of its first parent element (walking upwards in the HTML doc from the child) which has the `position:relative` pair.

In your CSS code, you simply set your parent element to `position:relative`, which does not change anything in your layout; it just tells your page that any child of the element X having `position:relative`, which has `position:absolute` must use that X for the relative positioning using the four properties `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. And yeah, obviously, as soon as you set a HTML child of a parent having `position:relative` to `position:absolute`, it will be placed above it.